# EF4.1 How to map properties to columns

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, metadata, poco

Assume I have this class:

```
class MyDataStore
{
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public int DataStoreType { get; set; }
   public Name { get; set; }
   public List<string> ExtendedProperties { get; set;  }
}
```

I have the following tables in my DB:

```
MyDataStore
Id            Name     DataStoreType
-----------------------------------------
someguid1     ABC         1


MyDataStoreExtended
DataStoreId     Property1    Property2
----------------------------------------
someguid1        value1       value2
```

Another table stores what extended properties my "MyDataStore" has:

```
MyDataStoreMetadata
Property     DataStoreType
-------------------------------------------
Property1      1
Property2      1
Property3      2
Property4      2
Property5      2
```

Now what are different ways I can map this data schema to my "MyDataStoreClass" using EF 4.1 code-first?

Note: I do not want to delcare "MyDataStoreExtended" class as my POCO, just want to use it for storing data.

Comment: What should be in `ExtendedProperties` property? `MyDataStoreExtended.Property1` or `MyDataStoreExtended.Property2`?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you are using it, you could wrap MyDataStore in MyDataStoreExtended:

```
class MyDataStoreExtended
{
   public MyDataStore MyDataStore { get; set; }
   public int DataStoreId { get; set; }
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```